# Encountered org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException distributing chat feature by springboot kafka react on ec2

Tags: spring-boot, docker, amazon-ec2, apache-kafka, docker-compose

##### I am distributing my school project on ec2 and I used kafka to make chatting feature.

##### The feature worked well on my local and local docker-compose,

##### but I encountered such error log when the browser client send a message.

```
2023-06-08 06:54:41.566  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.c.chat.service.ChatPreHandler          : preSend start2023-06-08 06:54:41.567 DEBUG 1 --- [nboundChannel-2] o.s.m.s.b.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler     : Processing CONNECT session=h1y3n5uk2023-06-08 06:54:41.616  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] c.c.chat.service.ChatPreHandler          : preSend start2023-06-08 06:54:41.617 DEBUG 1 --- [nboundChannel-1] o.s.m.s.b.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler     : Processing SUBSCRIBE /topic/1&4 id=sub-0 session=h1y3n5uk2023-06-08 06:54:42.042  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:3, serverValue:126}] to mongodb:270172023-06-08 06:54:47.381  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] c.c.chat.service.ChatPreHandler          : preSend start2023-06-08 06:54:47.492  INFO 1 --- [nboundChannel-2] c.contractB2B.chat.service.Sender        : sending data='Message(id=64817b37332dee424ea79feb, message=3개월?, userId=4, username=김동국, chatroomId=1&4, constructionId=1, constructionName=건국터널공사, timestamp=2023-06-08T06:54:47.398Z)' to topic='contractB2B-chatting'2023-06-08 06:54:47.584  INFO 1 --- [nboundChannel-2] o.a.k.clients.producer.ProducerConfig    : ProducerConfig values:acks = -1batch.size = 16384bootstrap.servers = [kafka:9092]buffer.memory = 33554432client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ipsclient.id = producer-1compression.type = noneconnections.max.idle.ms = 540000delivery.timeout.ms = 120000enable.idempotence = trueinterceptor.classes = []key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerSerializerlinger.ms = 0max.block.ms = 60000max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5max.request.size = 1048576metadata.max.age.ms = 300000metadata.max.idle.ms = 300000metric.reporters = []metrics.num.samples = 2metrics.recording.level = INFOmetrics.sample.window.ms = 30000partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitionerreceive.buffer.bytes = 32768reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000reconnect.backoff.ms = 50request.timeout.ms = 30000retries = 2147483647retry.backoff.ms = 100sasl.client.callback.handler.class = nullsasl.jaas.config = nullsasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinitsasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000sasl.kerberos.service.name = nullsasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8sasl.login.callback.handler.class = nullsasl.login.class = nullsasl.login.connect.timeout.ms = nullsasl.login.read.timeout.ms = nullsasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05sasl.login.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000sasl.login.retry.backoff.ms = 100sasl.mechanism = GSSAPIsasl.oauthbearer.clock.skew.seconds = 30sasl.oauthbearer.expected.audience = nullsasl.oauthbearer.expected.issuer = nullsasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.refresh.ms = 3600000sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.ms = 100sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.url = nullsasl.oauthbearer.scope.claim.name = scopesasl.oauthbearer.sub.claim.name = subsasl.oauthbearer.token.endpoint.url = nullsecurity.protocol = PLAINTEXTsecurity.providers = nullsend.buffer.bytes = 131072socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 30000socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000ssl.cipher.suites = nullssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = httpsssl.engine.factory.class = nullssl.key.password = nullssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = nullssl.keystore.key = nullssl.keystore.location = nullssl.keystore.password = nullssl.keystore.type = JKSssl.protocol = TLSv1.3ssl.provider = nullssl.secure.random.implementation = nullssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIXssl.truststore.certificates = nullssl.truststore.location = nullssl.truststore.password = nullssl.truststore.type = JKStransaction.timeout.ms = 60000transactional.id = nullvalue.serializer = class org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
```

```
2023-06-08 06:54:47.622  INFO 1 --- [nboundChannel-2] o.a.k.clients.producer.KafkaProducer     : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Instantiated an idempotent producer.2023-06-08 06:54:47.664  INFO 1 --- [nboundChannel-2] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version: 3.1.22023-06-08 06:54:47.665  INFO 1 --- [nboundChannel-2] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId: f8c67dc3ae0a32652023-06-08 06:54:47.667  INFO 1 --- [nboundChannel-2] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka startTimeMs: 16862072876642023-06-08 06:54:47.709  INFO 1 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Resetting the last seen epoch of partition contractB2B-chatting-0 to 8 since the associated topicId changed from null to E38m3s--QP-3gSys7G3CIg2023-06-08 06:54:47.709  INFO 1 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Cluster ID: q3bmmPCnQhS_GOGDEPIBnA2023-06-08 06:54:47.722  INFO 1 --- [ad | producer-1] o.a.k.c.p.internals.TransactionManager   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] ProducerId set to 8000 with epoch 02023-06-08 06:55:05.673  INFO 1 --- [MessageBroker-1] o.s.w.s.c.WebSocketMessageBrokerStats    : WebSocketSession[2 current WS(2)-HttpStream(0)-HttpPoll(0), 2 total, 0 closed abnormally (0 connect failure, 0 send limit, 0 transport error)], stompSubProtocol[processed CONNECT(2)-CONNECTED(2)-DISCONNECT(0)], stompBrokerRelay[null], inboundChannel[pool size = 2, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 15], outboundChannel[pool size = 2, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 2], sockJsScheduler[pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 3, completed tasks = 10]2023-06-08 06:56:47.762 ERROR 1 --- [ad | producer-1] o.s.k.support.LoggingProducerListener    : Exception thrown when sending a message with key='null' and payload='Message(id=64817b37332dee424ea79feb, message=3개월?, userId=4, username=김동국, chatroomId=1&4, construct...' to topic contractB2B-chatting:
```

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for contractB2B-chatting-0:120000 ms has passed since batch creation
```

##### I used docker-compose to build container`your text`

```
version: "3"
services:
  server:
    image: my-dockerhub-id/contractb2b-server:6.0
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - mongodb
      - kafka
    networks:
      - contractB2B-net
    restart: always

  view:
    image: my-dockerhub-id/contractb2b-view:1.0
    ports:
      - 80:3000
    networks:
      - contractB2B-net
    restart: always

  mysql:
    image: my-dockerhub-id/contractb2b-mysql:1.0
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: contractb2b
    networks:
      - contractB2B-net
    restart: always

  mongodb:
    image: my-dockerhub-id/contractb2b-mongodb:1.0
    ports:
      - 27018:27017
    networks:
      - contractB2B-net
    restart: always

  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "true"
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
    networks:
      - contractB2B-net
    restart: always

  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    networks:
      - contractB2B-net
    restart: always

networks:
  contractB2B-net:
    driver: bridge
```

##### Here are the classes about kafka in my spring boot project

- application.yml

```
kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: kafka:9092
    consumer:
      group-id: spring-boot-test
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    producer:
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
```

- websocketconfig

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private ChatPreHandler chatPreHandler;

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/chatting").setAllowedOriginPatterns("*").withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
        log.info("configureClientInboundChannel start");
        registration.interceptors(chatPreHandler);
    }
}
```

- kafkaconfig

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfig {

    @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;
    @Value("${spring.kafka.consumer.group-id}")
    private String groupId;

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, Message> producerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs(), null, new JsonSerializer<Message>());
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, Message> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }


    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> configMap = new HashMap<>();
        configMap.put("bootstrap.servers", bootstrapAddress);
        configMap.put("key.serializer", IntegerSerializer.class);
        configMap.put("value.serializer", JsonSerializer.class);
        return configMap;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Message> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Message> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, Message> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(), null, new JsonDeserializer<>(Message.class));
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> configMap = new HashMap<>();
        configMap.put("bootstrap.servers", bootstrapAddress);
        configMap.put("group.id", groupId);
        configMap.put("key.deserializer", IntegerDeserializer.class);
        configMap.put("value.deserializer", JsonDeserializer.class);

        return configMap;
    }
}
```

- sender

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class Sender {
    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, Message> kafkaTemplate;

    public void send(String topic, Message data) {
        log.info("sending data='{}' to topic='{}'", data, topic);
        kafkaTemplate.send(topic, data);
    }
}
```

-receiver

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class Receiver {
    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate template;

    @KafkaListener(id = "main-listener", topics = "contractB2B-chatting")
    public void receive(Message message) throws Exception {
        log.info("message='{}'", message);
        HashMap<String, String> msg = new HashMap<>();
        msg.put("timestamp", message.getTimestamp().toString());
        msg.put("message", message.getMessage());
        msg.put("username", message.getUsername());
        msg.put("userId", message.getUserId());
        msg.put("chatroomId", message.getChatroomId());
        msg.put("constructionId", message.getConstructionId());
        msg.put("constructionName", message.getConstructionName());

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(msg);

        this.template.convertAndSend("/topic/" + message.getConstructionId(), json);
        this.template.convertAndSend("/topic/" + message.getChatroomId(), json);
        this.template.convertAndSend("/topic/public", json);
    }
}
```

- controller

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = {"ws://localhost:3000", "ws://my-ec2-ip", "ws://my-ec2-ip"})
public class ChatController {

    @Autowired
    private Sender sender;

    @Autowired
    private Receiver receiver;

    @Autowired
    private MessageRepository messageRepository;

    private static String BOOT_TOPIC = "contractB2B-chatting";
    
    @MessageMapping("/message")
    public void sendMessage(Message message) throws Exception {
        messageRepository.save(message);
        sender.send(BOOT_TOPIC, message);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/history/{chatroomId}")
    public List<Message> getChattingHistory(@PathVariable String chatroomId) throws Exception {
        return messageRepository.findAllByChatroomId(chatroomId);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/history/construction/{constructionId}")
    public List<Message> getChattingHistoryByConstruction(@PathVariable String constructionId) throws Exception {
        return messageRepository.findAllByConstructionId(constructionId);
    }

}
```

##### It worked well on my local and i opened all the ports about kafka and zookeeper on my ec2 inbound rule.

##### Please somebody help me.